Alias not finding any components in NextJS

Hello, i dont really know why my @/components/ dont find any components, i have a header component for test:
import React from 'react';

export default function header() {
  return <div><header> hi </header></div>;
}

I tried to change my tsconfig to add the paths but it seems to not work, i tried to restart the app by control + c and running npm run dev again to see if it fix but it didnt
my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",

    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"],
      "@styles/*": ["styles/*"],
      "@/config/*": ["config/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    ".next/types/**/*.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "app/components/UldamanLogo.js",
    "app/page.js"
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


If you export it as a default, you need to import like:
import Header from '@components/header'

Or you could add a barrel file components/index.ts that has the line:
export Header from '@components/header'
which will allow you to write
import { Header}  from '@components'
